# How to handle timed popups using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

I am unable to find any guide on how to handle timed popups properly. My goal is to shut a popup down because it interupts selenium from interacting with the site when it's open. The biggest issue is that the timing on the popup is not the same each time I open the site, it varies.

I've tried inserting a simple 'try' method into the code to a place where the code is being executed when the popup appears but that does not work due to the variable popup timing.

```
def pop_up_off(self):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a_css_selector').click()
        sleep(.5)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Expected result is to get rid of the variable timed popup that interupts with ongoing selenium scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `While` loop and `WebdriverWait` where mentioned `timeout` and `poll_frequency` to check the presence of elements if does it will click on elements and break the loop else continue up to timeout.Hope this helps.

```
while(True):
  elements=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 300,1 ).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a_css_selector')))
  if(len(elements)>0):
      self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a_css_selector').click()
      break
  else:
    continue
```

Please note : You need to use following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**EDITED**

```
while(True):
  elements=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a_css_selector')
  if(len(elements)>0):
      self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a_css_selector').click()
      break
  else:
    continue
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work. The only problem with this is that the script stops and wait until the pop up comes up. That slows it down drastically. Is there any way to actually have the script going and the loop to be executed constantly in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an explicit wait for this kind of situation. It will wait for the given condition to fulfill and no more. explicit waits check the condition every half a second. If the condition doesn't meet in the given time, then it will throw a timeout exception.

Try this:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a_css_selector"))).click()
```

To use the explicit wait you have to import the followings

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you, does works. The problem with this solution is that the whole script stops and waits until the element is present. This slows it down drastically. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating a background thread that runs with your test does the trick if you don't want to wait for the popup on the beggining of the test.

```
import threading

trigger = True #if this trigger is set to False, the thread stops running.

def pop_up_off(self):
    while trigger == True:
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a_css_selector').click()
            trigger = False
        except Exception:
            pass
```

-

```
def test(your args):
    #your test before the popup page is opened...
    close_popup = threading.Thread(target=pop_up_off, args= your args)
    close_popup.start()
    #your test after the popup page is opened...
```

This will not make your test wait for the popup to appear to continue, it will try to detect and close the popup while the test is running

Hope it helps